# Как сделать в простом html сайте ссылки без html на конце

Tags: .htaccess

Хочу чтобы ссылки были такого вида: site.ru/xxx/ site.ru/xxx/xxx/ site.ru/xxx/xxx/xxx/ и т.д
Нужно именно правило в htacces, чтобы не прописывать редирект для каждой страницы.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Ну, хотите и что? Если пока не умеете писать правила сами, то можно воспользоваться [онлайн-генератором](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)

Answer (score 1):

Редирект с .html на без .html, т.е. с site.ru/article.html на site.ru/article (для тех кто сначала включил .html, а потом решил избавиться от него)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Рекомендую ознакомиться с [источником][1]

**Обновлено:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: это не работает.

Comment: Как сделать такое для Windows Server? В интернете хрен найдешь работающий рецепт.